# Display message based on QueryString

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

Why will this not display the failure text? This is using the same FailureText control that displays error messages for log in errors, such as invalid password, and locked or disabled accounts.

Would I have to setup a new control and use that, and if so how?

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Request.QueryString("suspended") IsNot Nothing Then

        If Request.QueryString("suspended").ToString() = "true" Then

            LoginUser.FailureText = "Your account has been Suspended - Contact the system administrator"

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is code is works fine:

```
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.Request.QueryString("suspended")) Then
        If Me.Request.QueryString("suspended").ToLower() = "true" Then
            Me.Login1.FailureText = "Your account has been Suspended - Contact the system administrator"
        End If
    End If
```

note that this method sets FailureText of login control and in first look, it seems nothing happen. But after you setup this, if login fails, your string will appear .

Answer (score 0):

Is it a casing issue of the query string key?

Try this:

```
If Request.QueryString("suspended").ToString().ToLower() = "true" Then
    LoginUser.FailureText = "Your account has been Suspended - Contact the system administrator"
End If
```